# boto3 conditionally delete in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dynamoDB DataBase with the following schema:

```
user    id    payload
123     abcd   some value
456     abcd   some value
```

How do i delete the id abcd corresponding to user 456?  what if user 456 didn't exist?  I tried:

```
try:
    resource.delete_item(
    Key={'user': 456,
        'id': 'abcd'
        })
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print("DeletePortfolio Successful...")
```

I always end up getting the statement "DeletePortfolio Successful" even if i put a random user like 478, or keep the user 456 and put an incorrect id like 'defg'.  How do i do a conditional delete only if key and value is present?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Hope this helps anybody out there

```
def deleteItem(user, id):
    try:
        resource.delete_item(
           Key={'user': user, 'id': id},
           ConditionExpression='attribute_exists(id)'
           )
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] in ['ConditionalCheckFailedException',
         'ParamVAlidationError']:
              print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print("delete successful")
```

Comment: Hey, I haven't found anyone who has even come close to this, so I thought I'd ask you directly: do you know how you would do it so that the condition isn't that the attribute exists, rather, that it isn't duplicated?

Comment: i asked this 2 years ago.  I haven;'t worked on dynamodb since then.  so can't really help you sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found this via Google and will probably need it in future.

Given a DDB table with a partition key of `id`, and an extra attribute `Test`, we can delete a row only if the value of `Test == foo` like so:

```
import json
import boto3
import botocore

dynamo_db = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        response = dynamo_db.delete_item(
            TableName='TestTable',
            Key={'id': {'S': 'myID'}},
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                '#sk': 'Test'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':sk': {'S': 'bar'},
            },
            ConditionExpression='#sk = :sk'
        )
        return response
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
            print("conditional delete failed because attribute did not match")
        else:
            raise e
    print('done')
```

For simple field names and values, the `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` parameters are possibly redundant, but more rigorous in case of special characters in the field.

The reason this conditional delete is useful is that DynamoDB is eventually consistent (by default). Let's say you're tracking sessions - a process might run to delete a session on a disconnection, but the user may reconnect in the meantime. If you're partition key is the user ID in that case, you don't want to delete the **new** session if the row has been updated in between triggering and deleting. So a conditional delete lets you verify that you're deleting the old row by checking a specific attribute (say, a timestamp or something).

Comment: Thanks for tagging me @shearn89, I appreciate the follow up! If I'm understanding you correctly, this is how you would check to see if some attribute (i.e. Test) was equal to some value (i.e. bar) and only delete the items/rows that match, right? To adapt that to my situation of wanting to delete duplicate sort_keys, I would check to see the attribute (i.e. sort_key) was equal to the same sort_key attribute? Wouldn't that delete all of them, instead of just the duplicate(s)?

Comment: For sort keys it's different, as they're part of the Primary Key of the table and so you can't have duplicate combinations of partition & sort key - DDB won't let you.

Comment: I've added a paragraph to the answer :)

Comment: Sure, sort_key was a bad example. Let it be some other attribute. The question regarding duplicates still stands.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it as easily. If you need a non-duplicate attribute, sounds like that needs to be part of the key...?